# How to deal with transactions when creating a database connection for each query

Tags: c#, database, sql-server

In line with this post [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query) I am going to change my website to create a connection per query to take advantage of .NET's connection pooling. With this in mind, I don't know how I should deal with transactions. At the moment I do something like (psuedo code):

```
GlobalTransaction = GlobalDBConnection.BeginTransaction();
try
{
    ExecSQL("insert into table ..")
    ExecSQL("update some_table ..")
    ....
    GlobalTransaction.Commit();
}catch{
    GlobalTransaction.Rollback();
    throw;
}
```

ExecSQL would be like this:

```
using (SqlCommand Command = GlobalDBConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    Command.Connection = GlobalDBConnection;
    Command.Transaction = GlobalTransaction;
    Command.CommandText = SQLStr;
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to change this concept to deal with transactions if the connection is created within `ExecSQL` because I would want the transaction to be shared between both the insert and update routines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) for transactions in .NET:

```
using(var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
    ExecSQL("insert into table ..")
    ExecSQL("update some_table ..")
    ....
    tx.Complete();
}
```

The above code will ensure both statements will belong to one transaction.

You can nest `TransactionScope`s if needed.

Comment: Just keep in mind that transactions will escalate to a distributed transaction if you are connecting to different data sources.  MS DTC (Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator) would then be needed to facilitate those types of scenarios.